# Can I change Openzeppelin access control without having the right permissions?

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts, modifiers, access

If you check this link: [openzeppelin github access control](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol)
you will notice they use 2 function for granting a role:

```
function grantRole(bytes32 role, address account) public virtual override onlyRole(getRoleAdmin(role)) {
        _grantRole(role, account);
    }
```

This function is external. All what it does it calling the internal function `_grantRole`. Note they add the modifier `onlyRole` which means if you dont have the right permissions (role), then the call will fail.

However, this is the internal function:

```
function _grantRole(bytes32 role, address account) internal virtual {
        if (!hasRole(role, account)) {
            _roles[role].members[account] = true;
            emit RoleGranted(role, account, _msgSender());
        }
    }
```

note that the internal function does not have the modifier `onlyRole` which means it does not do permission checking. As an internal function, I can write a contract and inherit this contract from openzeppelin and since my contract is derived contract, I have access to the internal functions, and I can easily write a function that call the internal function "_grantRole". Why that wont work? I dont understand the security behind this since only the external functions check for the role, but the internal ones dont.

Any contract can inherit this and call the internal functions. Would someone please explain!

Answer (score 2):

This is by design.

OpenZeppelin contracts are meant to be inherited and easy to use for different scenarios. They often offer this kind of default external or public function, which is secure, but they also offer the possibility to write your own logic around the internal function.

So you can create for example create your own function `grantRole2` which does something else, but inside it you call also `_grantRole`. This way you can change/extend the default external functionality.

If you are inheriting OpenZeppelin contracts you have free access to ruin the contracts' security as you wish. The default exposed functions are secure, but they allow you to also go around the default functionality.

It's your responsibility to make sure the external/public functions you write are secure.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I understand that this way allows us to reuse the internal functions which is great. However, by inheriting this contract and calling the internal function (me without having the right permission) and add myself as admin is a huge security gap. So the only way to secure my contract is override all the internal functions and add the modifier `onlyRole` to them? Thanks again!

Comment: Internal functions are not callable from outside. Keeping the default functionality doesn't expose any security threats. Only if you implement your own public functions which bypass the OZ's security (by calling the internal functions directly) you may open new security holes